# Logitech Lua Scripting and Looping

Tags: loops, lua, repeat, logitech

I'm having a little problem with my script here using a Logitech mouse. I will be using it for farming in a game.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then
    for i = 0, 300 do
            PressAndReleaseKey("f9")
            Sleep(400)
            PressAndReleaseKey("enter")
            Sleep(600)
            PressAndReleaseKey("f5")
            Sleep(50)
            PressMouseButton(1)
            Sleep(50)
            ReleaseMouseButton(1)
    end
            PressAndReleaseKey("1")
    repeat
    until IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
   end
end
```

So it will loop for 300 times and then press 1 when it's done, then repeat the loop again for 300 times, so on & so on. Problem I'm facing is, when I'm trying to abort the script, it will first finish the for-loop before being stopped by using Right-click button(IsMouseButtonPressed(3)), which is really hard to time (300x is a lot)

How can I pause/stop it during the for-loop, would it be possible?

Comment: Your `repeat...until` loop is useless here.  Remove it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 0):

Frequently check if the button is pressed and break the loop.

Break up those long blocking Sleeps.

Instead of `Sleep(400)` consider doing something like

```
for i = 1, 400, 50 do
  Sleep(50)
  if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then break end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `break` to jump out of your for loop when `IsMouseButtonPressed(3)`

```lua
    for i = 0, 300 do
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
            break -- exit for loop.
        end
        PressAndReleaseKey("f9")
        Sleep(400)
        PressAndReleaseKey("enter")
        Sleep(600)
        PressAndReleaseKey("f5")
        Sleep(50)
        PressMouseButton(1)
        Sleep(50)
        ReleaseMouseButton(1)
    end
```

doing it like this means you can expect a maximum delay of  1.1 seconds due to the sleep calls, for the exit to be registered.

---

You could change your code by adding a function to poll `IsMouseButtonPressed(3)` during your sleep intervals.

```lua
local function MousePollingSleep(time)
    loopCount = time / 50
    for i = loopCount, 0, -1 do
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
            return false
        end
        sleepTime = (i >= 1 and 1 or i) * 50
        Sleep(sleepTime)
    end
    return true
end
```

and change your for loop to

```lua
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then
      repeat
          for i = 0, 300 do
              PressAndReleaseKey("f9")
              if MousePollingSleep(400) == false then break end
              PressAndReleaseKey("enter")
              if MousePollingSleep(600) == false then break end
              PressAndReleaseKey("f5")
              if MousePollingSleep(50) == false then break end
              PressMouseButton(1)
              if MousePollingSleep(50) == false then break end
              ReleaseMouseButton(1)
          end
          ReleaseMouseButton(1)
          PressAndReleaseKey("1")
      until IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
   end
end
```

Comment: Using `break` between press mouse and release mouse simulations is a bad idea: the mouse button may remain pressed after exiting from OnEvent.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff outside the for loop OP has `PressAndReleaseKey("1")` that should prevent it from getting stuck.

Comment: I now see that is a key press not a mouse button. I added a release call after the loop

Comment: First script works! Thank you very much for the fast response. Script is really running good. Happy new year and keep safe!

Comment: The first script works for 300x, and does not repeat.
The second and third script works perfectly. It repeats the code 300x and then loops it until I press the right click button. Thank you very much!